# Using a Closure inside a class to return a static function value

Tags: php, closures, static-methods, anonymous-function

I am just starting with Anonymous functions namely Closures and I've run into an issue. I am using the Closure to call a **static function** inside a **class called Project** to return a value in another **class called Application**. Below is a simplified version of my problem

```
    class Project{

         public function __construct(){

             self::ProcessParams(function() {

                        return Application::return_param('1');

                    }, 'param2', 'param3');

              }
         }

         public static function ProcessParams($param1, $param2, $param3){

           var_dump($param1);

         }

    }
```

My problem is the var_dump() in the ProcessParams function doesn't return the requested value but rather inserts the whole Project class into **$param1**

> object(Closure)#90 (1) { ["this"]=> object(Project)#34 (3) { ..... }

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks

Comment: You're dumping the closure, not what the closure returns.

Comment: You passing closure, so param1 becomes callable and you have to call it as a standard function - `$param1()` - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *call* the closure in order to retrieve it's return value:

```
var_dump($param1());
```

You can start here to learn more about anonymous functions: http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php